# Convert cassandra timeuuid with cqlsh copy command

Tags: cassandra, copy, date-formatting, cqlsh, timeuuid

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE logs (
transaction_id text,
timestamp timeuuid,
action text,
event text
)
```

which I have to copy to a csv at the end of the day. Timestamp needs to be converted into a human readable time format. Is it possible to do it with the copy command using cqlsh. I'm using

```
cqlsh>Copy logs (transaction_id,timestamp,action,event)  to '/tmp/logs.csv' with datetimeformat='%m/%d/%Y'
```

but this doesn't convert the timeuuid to %m/%d/%y.

Comment: Date time format only work for timestamp  and date

Comment: Unfortunately, `COPY` is not going to work for you here.  You might want to try writing your own exporter that SELECTs the `logs` data using `dateof(timestamp)` and then you can format it however you like.